# session time out in SiteMinder

Tags: siteminder

How to get the session timeout in Siteminder.In our application user will access via login to the Site minder. One peculiar problem is that if a user left idle in our application for about 20 minutes then after 20 minutes when he tries to access or do something it will give fatal exceptions

How to get the session time out from Siteminder.I am using Servlet filters for authentication.

Comment: There are two timeout periods in Siteminder configuration. One is idle timeout, which is usually like 20 mins. If you are idle for 20 mins, you will be asked to login again. There is another Max Timeout, which is usually set to something like 2 to 8 hours. After this timeout, the user will be asked to login again, even if session was busy/working sending/receiving messages all the time. Given this, what are you trying to do? If you are trying to increase them, you can do so in Siteminder configuration.

Comment: Thanks I made it work like this               `smSessionCookie=CookieUtility.getCookie(request,"SMSESSION",null);
    //Check if  SMSESSION:LOGGEDOFF =is true then invalidate session.
                if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(smSessionCookie) && smSessionCookie.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGGEDOFF")){
                    localSession.invalidate();
                    setSessionExpired(true);
                    return;
                } `

Comment: I see. I assume you are checking it in servlet filters to see if the session has expired. If so, reject the request and forward him to a page to get authenticated?